# Is there a way to know from which website an URL is being calling?

Tags: php

I have a URL and I call it from many web sites. Is there a way to know from which website the URL was called?

Comment: show your code? did u tried something?

Comment: Checking the referer *might* give you an idea, but this header can be spoofed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`, however you shouldn't trust it for security purposes as it can be altered very easily.

Comment: Also note, that it might be missing altogether: `if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)) { ... }`

Comment: in javascript use document.referrer;

Comment: thanks alpinehc , there isn't a sure way ?

Comment: Nope. Headers can be altered very easily either by browser extensions or curl requests, among others. Either way, you should only really ever use header data as information to record for marketing purposes etc. Using it for security will make your site extremely vulnerable.

Comment: ok thanks , i use also $_server['remote_addr'] for getting the visitor adress, is it sure or not ??

Comment: It is relatively safe. It is still possible to spoof an IP using NMAP but generally you can rely on the IP being genuine. I still wouldn't use it for security though simply because of the possibility of spoofing the IP. Also, if you need to make your script portable, you should be aware you will also need to check for X-Forwarded-For, as some server setups sit behind Load Balancers or Proxies which then pass the IP through using this header.

Comment: ok many thanks for these explanations , i need just clearing a point : $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] will work just if we use <a href="the url"></a> or it will get the info also if we use the url inside a js or php script ? like file_get_contents($url) ?

Comment: i did the test ... thanks alpinehc

Comment: Just a friendly heads up, you should accept the best answer to your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

you can put a Get variable in it and give it a different value for each site for exmeple :

```
www.exemple.com/?code=A1z2f4 //give this to site N1
www.exemple.com/?code=Bdf2f4 //give this to site N2
www.exemple.com/?code=Fmpo42 //give this to site N3
```

**PS :** you should have a table in your database where are stored the names and the codes :

```
sitename        |   code     | count

www.site1.com   |   A1z2f4   |   2

www.site2.com   |   Bdl2f4   |   6

www.site3.com   |   Fmpo42   |   0
```

then you can increase the number evrytime they use the link

Comment: i need a way which is not editable by the webmaster who have the website

Answer (score 0):

In java script use `document.referrer;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer